# Loop through table headers in excel with vba

Tags: excel, vba, header

`For Each headerRange In tblStueckpreis.Range.Rows(1)
If tblStueckpreis.DataBodyRange.Cells.Value Like "*Staffel*" Then
numbersStaffel = numbersStaffel + 1
End If
Next`

> I wanted to loop through the header of my table and check when the header says "Staffel". I've tried a lot of things and it doesn't work...
>   What am I doing wrong? Help me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to loop, just use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf()`
:

```
numbersStaffel = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(tblStueckpreis.Range.Rows(1), "*Staffel*")
```

should you need to stick with looping, then use:

```
For Each headerRange In tblStueckpreis.Range.Rows(1).Cells
    If headerRange.Value Like "*Staffel*" Then numbersStaffel = numbersStaffel + 1
Next
```

while you may want to be informed the your code had two issues:

1   you set up a loop like `For Each headerRange In tblStueckpreis.Range.Rows(1)` but never use its iterator variable (i.e.: `headerRange`) inside it

2   `tblStueckpreis.DataBodyRange.Cells.Value` would return a 2D array with all values of `tblStueckpreis` table, which you cannot compare to a `String` value

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer :). Now i understand what i did wrong

Comment: You are welcome. If it solves your question you may mark the answer as accepted to direct future readers too...